# Get data and sort from MySQL two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have `table_1` and `table_2` and they are the same structure, but different data. Need to get all the data from that tables in sort of `create_date` and no matter from which table (it can be 1 row from table_1, 3 rows from table_2 and then again from table_1). Is it possible? How? or shout I get two queries and then sort by date with PHP?

EDIT:
Sorry for first part, I thought I can do it from there, but seems like i can't :/

i have very big query like this

```
SELECT 
    table_1.id, 
    table_1.created, 
    table_1.qty, 
    table_1.comments, 
    table_1.last_update, 
    table_7.firstname, 
    SUBSTRING(table_7.lastname, 1, 1) AS lastname, 
    table_8.title country, 
    table_3.value AS sim, 
    table_1.offer_request, 
    table_5.manufacturer AS manufacturer, 
    table_4.name AS model, 
    table_6.value AS specifications, 
    table_9.value as shipping, 
    table_1.model AS mid, 
    table_1.user_id, 
    table_1.callme, 
    table_1.phoneprice, 
    table_1.phoneprice_eur, 
    table_1.currency, 
    table_1.sel_buy_show_all, 
    table_1.seller_buyer
FROM (`table_1`)

LEFT JOIN `table_3` ON `table_3`.`id` = `table_1`.`sim`
LEFT JOIN `table_4` ON `table_4`.`id` = `table_1`.`model`
LEFT JOIN `table_5` ON `table_5`.`id` = `table_1`.`manufacturer`
LEFT JOIN `table_6` ON `table_6`.`id` = `table_1`.`specifications`
LEFT JOIN `table_7` ON `table_7`.`id` = `table_1`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `table_8` ON `table_7`.`country`=`table_8`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `table_9` ON `table_9`.`id` = `table_1`.`types`
WHERE `table_1`.`status` =  '1'
AND `table_1`.`deleted` =  '0'
ORDER BY `last_update` DESC
LIMIT 200
```

And there is table_1 which structure is the same as table_2, and I need somehow to insert table_2 to the query with all joins like table_1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got your question right, you can use union like this -

```
select * from table_1 union select * from table_2 order by create_date desc
```

**EDIT**

Create a view like this -

```
create view table_1And2 as select * from table_1 union select * from table_2
```

table_1And2 is not a good name, give a meaningful name.

And modify your long query like this -

```
SELECT 
table_1And2.id, 
table_1And2.created, 
table_1And2.qty, 
table_1And2.comments, 
table_1And2.last_update, 
table_7.firstname, 
SUBSTRING(table_7.lastname, 1, 1) AS lastname, 
table_8.title country, 
table_3.value AS sim, 
table_1And2.offer_request, 
table_5.manufacturer AS manufacturer, 
table_4.name AS model, 
table_6.value AS specifications, 
table_9.value as shipping, 
table_1And2.model AS mid, 
table_1And2.user_id, 
table_1And2.callme, 
table_1And2.phoneprice, 
table_1And2.phoneprice_eur, 
table_1And2.currency, 
table_1And2.sel_buy_show_all, 
table_1And2.seller_buyer
FROM (`table_1And2`)

LEFT JOIN `table_3` ON `table_3`.`id` = `table_1And2`.`sim`
LEFT JOIN `table_4` ON `table_4`.`id` = `table_1And2`.`model`
LEFT JOIN `table_5` ON `table_5`.`id` = `table_1And2`.`manufacturer`
LEFT JOIN `table_6` ON `table_6`.`id` = `table_1And2`.`specifications`
LEFT JOIN `table_7` ON `table_7`.`id` = `table_1And2`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `table_8` ON `table_7`.`country`=`table_8`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `table_9` ON `table_9`.`id` = `table_1And2`.`types`
WHERE `table_1And2`.`status` =  '1'
AND `table_1And2`.`deleted` =  '0'
ORDER BY `last_update` DESC
LIMIT 200
```

Comment: yes, your answer for the first my question part is correct.. but still i couldn't get what i needed so i improved my question with my query, if you could help me :?

Comment: In that case, you can create a view with the above query and then instead of using `table_1` everywhere use the name of view you created in your long query. That will work.

Comment: em.. well.. i will try... but I have never before used view :)
and I would appreciate if you could set me on the road how I shoud do it

Comment: Getting error:
`create view table_1And2 as (select * from table_1 union select * from table_2)`

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'union select * from sells_buys)' at line 1 `

Comment: oh.. ;D yeas.. seems like it's working.. just now wondering.. if i will insert, update or delete record from `table_1` or `table_2`, will `table_1And2` update also? :O

Comment: NICE!! thank you very much! now my mysql skills level are bigger because of your advice to use views and union select, and still will read more about them, for better understanding! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Also I see the answer of @Rehban is a good one for you, I will produce another solution if you do not need `view`:

```
SELECT 
mainTable.id, 
mainTable.created, 
mainTable.qty, 
mainTable.comments, 
mainTable.last_update, 
table_7.firstname, 
SUBSTRING(table_7.lastname, 1, 1) AS lastname, 
table_8.title country, 
table_3.value AS sim, 
mainTable.offer_request, 
table_5.manufacturer AS manufacturer, 
table_4.name AS model, 
table_6.value AS specifications, 
table_9.value as shipping, 
mainTable.model AS mid, 
mainTable.user_id, 
mainTable.callme, 
mainTable.phoneprice, 
mainTable.phoneprice_eur, 
mainTable.currency, 
mainTable.sel_buy_show_all, 
mainTable.seller_buyer
FROM (Select * From `table_1` union Select * From `table_2`) as mainTable

LEFT JOIN `table_3` ON `table_3`.`id` = `mainTable `.`sim`
LEFT JOIN `table_4` ON `table_4`.`id` = `mainTable `.`model`
LEFT JOIN `table_5` ON `table_5`.`id` = `mainTable `.`manufacturer`
LEFT JOIN `table_6` ON `table_6`.`id` = `mainTable `.`specifications`
LEFT JOIN `table_7` ON `table_7`.`id` = `mainTable `.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `table_8` ON `table_7`.`country`=`table_8`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `table_9` ON `table_9`.`id` = `mainTable `.`types`
WHERE `mainTable `.`status` =  '1'
AND `mainTable `.`deleted` =  '0'
ORDER BY `last_update` DESC
LIMIT 200
```

Comment: i don't know why, but I would like more to use without view (but maybe view is also good idea, I don't know which is better in performace) 

but if I using your query i'm getting error like this
`#1054 - Unknown column 'table_1.id' in 'field list'`